# Interior, Closure topology example stuck

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm stuck on this question $$U = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \geq 1 \}$$. Find the closure, interior and boundary of $U$.

So, I have the solution but I'm not sure how to do it; more precisely, I'm not sure how to think about it

For ref the solution for closure is: $$\bar{U} = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \geq 1 \} \ \cup \ \{0\} $$

I know the defition of closure which is defined to be "$x \in X$ called closure pt. of $U$ if all neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect $U$"

But, I don't understand it in this statement and solution. Do we find all nbhds of $x$ and then all nbhds of $U$ and then intersect and then find this to be the closure?

I'm very stuck and if someone could give a simplified way of understanding this it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean all neighbourhoods of $x$ instead of $X$?

Comment: It shouldn't be a surprise that $U$ is contained in $U$'s closure.  The only hew point in the closure is $0$.  It is enough to check open intervals containing $0$.  Can you write a specific (meaning, using honest real numbers as its bounds) open interval containing $0$ and then check to see if $U$ has empty or nonempty intersection with that interval?  Can you repeat that process with a generic open interval $(a,b)$ with $a < 0 < b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U$ is a metric space, so the closure of $U$ consists of all limits of sequences in $U$. It is not difficult to see that the only point a sequence in $U$ may converge to outside of $U$ itself is $0$ and the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is such a sequence. Hence $\overline{U} = U \cup \{0 \}$. The interior of $U$ is empty because for any $\frac{1}{n} \in U$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, the ball $B( \frac{1}{n}, \varepsilon)$ contains points outside of $U$. Hence, $U = \emptyset$. Then the boundary $\partial U$ is $\partial U = \overline{U} - \text{int}(U) = \{0 \}.$

Comment: Thank you very much